# python 3.9 Installation failure on windows

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, windows

Building wheels for collected packages: oommfpy
Building wheel for oommfpy (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\Hostx64\x86\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

Comment: Please enter complete code and context.

Comment: install buildtools(pip install buildtools) before installing desired package. Please add more details, so we can help you answer your question.

Comment: What is the module `oommfpy` that you are trying to install?